# Turning flat array values into column vectors

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I have an array of base 3 numbers expressed as strings:

```
['1', '2', '10']
```

I want to 0 pad each number such that the max spaces taken up by each is three.

```
['001', '002', '010']
```

And then convert  it to a matrix which is the following:

```
[[0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 1],
[1, 2, 0]]
```

That is, to convert each string entry into a column vector. I've tried rotation, transpose, and not sure what the best way to do this is.

Thanks

Comment: do you need the intermediary step, or is it sufficient to produce the matrix?

Comment: Just need the matrix; if there's a better way to get it without the intermediary step that works! Thanks

Comment: ok have posted a solution below that gives both list & numpy array.

Comment: @epic566, if one of the answers below helped, feel free to accept one (tick on left) so that other users can see a tested solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `str.zfill` to pad with zeros and then `np.dstack` to convert the the expected format:

```
In [106]: np.dstack([list(i.zfill(3)) for i in a])[0].astype(np.int)
Out[106]: 
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [1, 2, 0]])
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way. I haven't split apart the intermediary step, but that's easily done.

```
lst = ['1', '2', '10']
result = list(zip(*(map(int, i.zfill(3)) for i in lst)))
```

If you want a `numpy` array:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array(result)

# array([[0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 0, 1],
#        [1, 2, 0]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `numpy.char` module which provides vectorized versions of many string operations:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> 
>>> a = np.array((1,2,10),'U2')
>>> a
array(['1', '2', '10'],
      dtype='<U2')
>>> 
>>> b = np.char.zfill(a, 3)
>>> b
array(['001', '002', '010'],
      dtype='<U3')
>>> 
>>> c = b.view('U1').reshape(3, 3).T.astype(int)
>>> c
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [1, 2, 0]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code. Explanation is added as comments:

```
lst = ['1', '2', '10']       # input list
outlist = []                 # empty output list
for i in lst:
    while len(i) <3:
        i = '0'+i           # add leading 0s
    outlist.append(list(i)) # string converted to list and added to output list

# convert to np.array, then to integers, transpose and convert back to list:
outlist = np.array(outlist).astype(np.int).T.tolist()    
print(outlist)
```

Output:

```
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [1, 2, 0]]
```